# How to change next-text,previous-text in ngb-pagination

Tags: ng-bootstrap

Everyone,Hi

I really want to change the next-text ">>" which now is in pagination with another word, for example something like "Next". but there is no Inputs be exported.
How to do this?

Comment: Could anyone help me out ? Please.

Comment: I just found that [angular-ui/bootstrap] has the property for this. But ng-bootstrap has no it. How to get this out.....

Comment: I give up ng-bootstrap, minna, forget this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is really old, but if anyone comes here looking for the same information.

In the related css file, you can do the following:

```
a[aria-label='Previous'] {
    span {
        display: none !important;
    }

    &::before {
        content: 'YourTextHere' !important;
    }
 }
```

The same can be done for the Next button by using `a[aria-label='Next']`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the  `<ng-template ngbPaginationNext>`  and  `<ng-template ngbPaginationNext>`

```
<ngb-pagination>
   <ng-template ngbPaginationPrevious>Your text for previous</ng-template>
   <ng-template ngbPaginationNext>Your text for next</ng-template>
   ...
</ngb-pagination>
```

This is documented here https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/examples#customization